# How to automatically select from one of multiple tables?

Tags: php, sql-server

I am very open to suggestions on my overall logic and design here if I am approaching this wrong. I will explain the problem and my solution first.

I have to collect a few types of data (varchar, money, real, bit) but could collect 0-1000+ of each type per record. For instance, record 1 could have 40 varchar fields, and 500 money fields, that need to be stored.

So I thought I would make 4 tables, one per data type, as below. Data for theoretical record number 1 shown below:

```
    -----------------------------------------------
    |record(int)|fieldname(varchar)|value(varchar)|
    |-----------|------------------|--------------|
    |1          |field1            |test a        |
    |1          |field2            |test b        |
    -----------------------------------------------
    (imagine 40 rows here total)

    -----------------------------------------------
    |record(int)|fieldname(varchar)|value(money)  |
    |-----------|------------------|--------------|
    |1          |field3            |111           |
    |1          |field4            |222           |
    -----------------------------------------------
    (imagine 500 rows here total)

    -----------------------------------------------
    |record(int)|fieldname(varchar)|value(real)   |
    |-----------|------------------|--------------|
    (no real data to store for record 1)

    -----------------------------------------------
    |record(int)|fieldname(varchar)|value(bit)    |
    |-----------|------------------|--------------|
    (no bit data to store for record 1)
```

I was considering making one table with 4 columns varchar, money, real, and bit. But then I would only be using 1 of the 4 columns per row and it didn't seem like the best way.

Is this a stupid design? Now the next question: How can I select the variable name from the correct table without having to specify the data type? Besides doing 4 separate queries until I get a result back. I was thinking of using 3 unions, manufacturing the 3 missing columns for each table. Is this the best way?

Comment: I will edit my question. When I say fields, I mean pieces of data. I did not want to make 500 rows in my example table, but imagine one row per piece of data. I will edit my question to clarify.

Comment: Having 4 columns of which 3 are NULL doesn't take any additional storage per record. The performance hit of querying 4 tables for the same record is probably more impactful in this scenario.

Comment: Jason W - I did not know that. I thought simply having a data type and row would use storage, even if it was null. I guess I will put them all in a single table then. Thank you!

Comment: Certainly! I put some additional details in the answer below. I think you'll be fine with 4 columns in this scenario, and then handle the display of the field at the application level based on the contents of those fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comment, SQL Server doesn't take additional storage per record for columns in the row that are null for variable length fields.

> Each row has a null bitmap for columns that allow nulls. If the row in
>   that column is null then a bit in the bitmap is 1 else it's 0.
>
> For variable size datatypes the acctual size is 0 bytes.
>
> For fixed size datatype the acctual size is the default datatype size
>   in bytes set to default value (0 for numbers, '' for chars).

For further reading: http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2007/09/06/How_does_SQL_Server_really_store_NULL-s.aspx

Comment: Thank you. I am a little embarrassed that a lack of fundamental understanding on my part almost led me to create some cumbersome, dirty solution for a problem that did not exist. Glad I asked here first!